# split line in C# Graphics

Tags: c#, graphics, drawing

I draw a line with

```
Graphics gg = this.CreateGraphics();
Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Blue, 2);
gg.DrawLine(pen, Lines[0].StartPoint.X,  Lines[0].StartPoint.Y, 
                 Lines[0].EndPoint.X, Lines[0].EndPoint.Y);
```

How can I split this line into two parts... when I right click by mouse and choose split from a contextMenuStrip ,,, the line splite into three parts

```
gg.DrawLine(pen, Lines[0].StartPoint.X,  Lines[0].StartPoint.Y, 
                 mouseposition.X, mouseposition.Y);
gg.DrawLine(pen, mouseposition.X, mouseposition.Y,
                 Lines[0].EndPoint.X, Lines[0].EndPoint.Y);
```

Comment: How can it split into three parts, when you are drawing only two parts? Or are you still calling the `DrawLine` of the first code snippet?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know enough about your drawing logic. Maybe this helps: Instead of drawing two line parts explicitly, try to change your `Line` list accordingly. (I assume it's a `List<T>`, not an array).

```
var line = new Line{ StartPoint = mouseposition, EndPoint = Lines[0].EndPoint };
Lines.Add(line);
Lines[0].EndPoint = mouseposition;
```

Now you can always call `DrawLine` once in a loop.

```
Graphics gg = this.CreateGraphics();
Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Blue, 2);

foreach (Line line in Lines) {
    gg.DrawLine(pen, line.StartPoint.X, line.StartPoint.Y,
                     line.EndPoint.X, line.EndPoint.Y);
}
```